# Create a concatenated table from another table using function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a function `GetChildren(@id uniqueidentifier)` that returns a table of nodes and a table of parents deleted from delete trigger
I want to make a big table of nodes concatenating output of GetChildren for each row.Id of deleted, how do I do that? Please, say how to make it without variables and loops in only pure sql-way

I want something similar to SelectMany from linq c#

example:

`deleted` table

```
+-----+
| Id  |
+-----+
| 111 |
+-----+
| 222 |
+-----+
```

`Nodes` table

```
+-----+----------+
| Id  | ParentId |
+-----+----------+
| 111 | ...      |
+-----+----------+
| 222 | ...      |
+-----+----------+
| 333 | ...      |
+-----+----------+
| 444 | 111      |
+-----+----------+
| 555 | null     |
+-----+----------+
| 666 | 222      |
+-----+----------+
```

`GetChildren('111')` will produce:

```
+-----+
| Id  |
+-----+
| 111 |
+-----+
| 444 |
+-----+
```

`GetChildren('222')` will produce:

```
+-----+
| Id  |
+-----+
| 222 |
+-----+
| 666 |
+-----+
```

I want to get table that is concatenation of 2 above:

```
+-----+
| Id  |
+-----+
| 111 |
+-----+
| 444 |
+-----+
| 222 |
+-----+
| 666 |
+-----+
```

If `deleted` would contain 4 rows I want to concatenate all 4 outputs of `GetChildren` for each row

Comment: The parent  child is one level only or could be recursive ?   child of child ..an so on.. ?

Comment: @scaisEdge yes, it's recursive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [CROSS APPLY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#k-using-apply) to return and union multiple resultsets from a table valued function based on rows from another table. In your example that would look like:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM deleted d
CROSS APPLY GetChildren(d.Id) c
```

Comment: Can I do this for stored procedures the same way?

Comment: No, this only works for user defined functions. To do something similar for a stored procedure you would need to do something like create a temp table then use a cursor to loop over the rows and insert the resultset of each procedure call into the temp table.